# Extracting nested data values in R

Tags: json, r, extract

How would I extract item 3 If I have a nested json list Like this

```
[
 {
  "item1": null, 
  "item2": false, 
  "item3": "chr", 
  "item4": {
   "a": [], 
   "b": [
    {
     "a": 36659026, 
     "b": [
      3, 
      16
     ], 
     "c": "num"
    }, 
    {
  "item1": null, 
  "item2": false, 
  "item3": "chr", 
  "item4": {
   "a": [], 
   "b": [
    {
     "a": 36659026, 
     "b": [
      3, 
      16
     ], 
     "c": "num"
    },
    ]
```

I have tried the following code:

```
library(RJSONIO)
library(jsonlite)
# url with JSON content
data1 = "file.json"

data2 = readLines(data1)

#contacating all data into a single string
data2_str = paste(data2, collapse = "")

data3 = RJSONIO::fromJSON(data2_str)
```

I can extract iten 3  with the following command

```
 text.1 <- c(data3[[1]]$text)
```

but there are 500 item4 in the dataset how to extract all of them.

Comment: I don't want to install RJSONIO (a minimal example would just provide `dput(data3[1:3])`), but at a wild guess: `sapply(data3,  "[[", i = "text")`.

Comment: a link to a more complete JSON example would help

Comment: Thank you Roland your answer helped a lot